# I'm trying to make a petal fall animation, but I'm not sure where to start

Tags: rendering, animation, physics, eevee-render-engine

I wanted to make a video just like this of rose petals falling in blender but i'm not sure what to do physics-wise. I tried making an explosion with the rose mesh but it resulted kind of uneven and not that great to look at. I was thinking maybe to subdivide the rose into individual petals and then give those a rigid body, but how would I go about the "bounce" that you see in the video? the petals in the video deform and look like they have weight, and I'm not sure how to achieve that. Does anybody have any ideas?

[Here is the video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13M2Rta_hZJDqKUiEUiaNEet1JSK9BJy8/view?usp=sharing)

[image: screenshot from the video]

thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You'll probably need a soft-body on the petals, as well as collision set up with the ground

Comment: focefields perhaps?